# Interdependent filtering of selectors in R Shiny

Tags: r, shiny, reactive

I have a problem it seems to me with reactive expressions in the code. I'm using `selectizeGroupUI` and it works ok, the selectors are dependent on each other. However, when I want to go back and change the date range, the other selectors go back to their default values and are empty.

I found a few other topics discussing the same problem, but I'm not sure how to apply the solution to mine.

[image]

***My code in shiny:***

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyWidgets)
library(plotly)
library(dplyr)
library(magrittr)
library(DT)
library(lubridate)
library(tidyr)

ui <- fluidPage(
  fluidRow(
    column(
      width = 10, offset = 1,
      tags$h3("Filter data with selectize group"),
      panel(dateRangeInput("date_range", label = "Date range:",
                           start = min(df_new$DATE),
                           end = max(df_new$DATE),
                           min = min(df_new$DATE),
                           max = max(df_new$DATE),
                           format = "yyyy-mm-dd",
                           startview = "year",
                           separator = " to "),
            selectizeGroupUI(
              id = "my-filters",
              params = list(
                CATEGORY = list(inputId = "CATEGORY", title = "CATEGORY:"),
                SOURCE = list(inputId = "SOURCE", title = "SOURCE:")
              )
            ),
            status = "primary"
      ),
      plotlyOutput("plot"),
      DT::dataTableOutput(outputId = "table")
      
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  dates_filter <- reactive({
    filter(df_new, DATE >= input$date_range[1] & DATE <= input$date_range[2])
      })
  
  res_mod <- callModule(
    module = selectizeGroupServer,
    id = "my-filters",
    data = dates_filter,
    vars = c("CATEGORY", "SOURCE")
  )
  
  dat <- reactive({
    req(res_mod())
    res_mod() %>%
      group_by(YEAR,DATE, MONTH, WEEK, WEEKDAYS) %>%
      summarise(Revenue_now = sum(REVENUE_2018),
                Revenue_pre = sum(REVENUE_2017)) %>%
      group_by(YEAR) %>%
      mutate(Revenue_now_cum = cumsum(Revenue_now),
             Revenue_pre_cum = cumsum(Revenue_pre))
  })
  
  output$table <- DT::renderDataTable({
    req(dat())
    dat()
  })
  
  output$plot <- renderPlotly({
    
    plot_ly(
      dat(),
      x = ~ DATE,
      y = ~ as.numeric(Revenue_now_cum),
      type = 'scatter',
      mode = 'lines+markers',
      name = "Selected year"
      
    ) %>%
      add_trace(y = ~ as.numeric(Revenue_pre_cum),
                mode = 'lines+markers',
                name = "Previous year"
      ) %>% layout(xaxis = list(type="category")) 
    
  })
}
shinyApp(ui, server)
```

***My data***

```
range_dates<-seq(as.Date('2017/01/01'), as.Date('2018/11/17'), by = "day")
DATE = rep(range_dates, 10)
CATEGORY = rep(sample(c("A","B","C"),10,T), each = length(range_dates))
SOURCE = rep(sample(c("aa","bb","cc"),10,T), each = length(range_dates))
REVENUE = as.numeric(sample(c(100:20000), length(range_dates) * 10, replace = T))
YEAR = year(DATE)
MONTH = months(DATE)
WEEKDAYS = weekdays(DATE)
WEEK = isoweek(DATE)
df <- data.frame(DATE, YEAR, MONTH, WEEK, WEEKDAYS, CATEGORY, SOURCE, REVENUE)

df_new<-df %>%
  group_by(YEAR) %>%
  mutate(row = row_number()) %>%
  tidyr::pivot_wider(names_from = YEAR, values_from = REVENUE, names_glue = "{.value}_{YEAR}") %>%
  select(-row)

df_new$YEAR = year(df_new$DATE)
year(df_new$DATE)<-2018
```

Comment: The `CATEGORY` and `SOURCE` change because they are reactive to the input dates - so when the input dates change, the `CATEGORY` and `SOURCE` refresh.

Comment: I know this but what should I do to make the new choice of dates remember previous selectors ```CATEGORY``` and ```SOURCE```?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure, if I understood all of your requirements, but why not simply making your `selectizeGroupUI` independent of your `input$date_range`?

```r
server <- function(input, output, session) {
   dates_filter <- reactive({
      filter(df_new, DATE >= input$date_range[1] & DATE <= input$date_range[2])
   })
   
   res_mod <- callModule(
      module = selectizeGroupServer,
      id = "my-filters",
      data = df_new,
      vars = c("CATEGORY", "SOURCE")
   )
   
   dat <- reactive({
      req(res_mod())
      req(dates_filter())
      res_mod() %>%
         group_by(YEAR,DATE, MONTH, WEEK, WEEKDAYS) %>%
         summarise(Revenue_now = sum(REVENUE_2018),
                   Revenue_pre = sum(REVENUE_2017)) %>%
         group_by(YEAR) %>%
         mutate(Revenue_now_cum = cumsum(Revenue_now),
                Revenue_pre_cum = cumsum(Revenue_pre))
   })
   
   output$table <- DT::renderDataTable({
      req(dat())
   })
   
   output$plot <- renderPlotly({
      plot_ly(
         dat(),
         x = ~ DATE,
         y = ~ as.numeric(Revenue_now_cum),
         type = 'scatter',
         mode = 'lines+markers',
         name = "Selected year"
         
      ) %>%
         add_trace(y = ~ as.numeric(Revenue_pre_cum),
                   mode = 'lines+markers',
                   name = "Previous year"
         ) %>% layout(xaxis = list(type="category")) 
      
   })
}
```

The moment you take the dependency on `input$date_range` it is by design that your `selectizeGroupUI` will update. What would be otherwise the expeced behaviour, if you selected `A` as the category and then change the dates to a filter range, where there is no `CATEGORY == 'A'`?

To make a long story short:

1. If your filter elements should show only values which are existing in the selected date range, you should take a dependency, but you have to live with the fact that with every change it is reset (you can work around that, but more likely than not you will introduce nasty race conditions).
2. If the choices of the filters should not be effected by the date range, simply remove the dependency.